# Why parameters are encoded when sent through HTTP request?

Tags: asp.net, http, web-applications, https

I am curious to know the reasons why the HTTP request encodes(URLEncoded) all the parameters before sending it across the network in POST request.

Comment: Does it really? Wouldn't depend on how you specify the <form> tag's content?

Comment: Yes, check with the fiddler or HTTPFox. Enter some text in textbox and say submit to server with <form method= "post" >. When received on the server side they are automatically decoded again so when on server we read say Request.params['key'] decoded value is displayed.

Comment: Yes but have you set the content type? Default is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" if not.

Comment: O so if we set it to something else do we have to explicitly handle decoding on the server end ?

Comment: IF not asp.net will handle it, yes.

Answer (score -1):

So that they are convertible among different systems, eg. windows client talking to unix server...

Comment: Why vote down? If you don't encode them they might not be readable among systems that have different character encodings.

Comment: Thats what we have Content-Encoding for in HTTP. URIEncoding doesn't prevent encoding incompabilities.

Comment: But Content-Encodig is just for the content, and you may use Unicode in uris which should be correctly encoded, right?

Comment: The stream is the content. We are talking about postdata ie, content. Not the query.